# Javascript - Error in hiding and calling specific "Div" (Calling specific div - onchange)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dropdown box to list 2015/2016 years. Each is provided as a div, under which it has radio buttons for (Monthly & Weekly).

If i select 2015 in dropdown - 2015 Monthly & Weekly should be view.
Same for 2016.

My issue is, both the year's div are viewed together in same page.
Could someone give a suggestion please. Thanks for your time and help.

My JS Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <select  class="dropdown"  id="year" name="year" size="1" onchange="changeDiv('year');">
      <option value="2015" selected="selected">2015</option>
      <option value="2016">2016</option> 
    </select>

    <div id="2015">
      <B>AAAAAAA</B>
      <input type="radio"   checked="checked" onclick="javascript:changeDiv('2015Monthly');" />Monthly
      <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:changeDiv('2015Weekly');" align="left" />Weekly

      <div id="2015Monthly" ><B>2015 - Monthly</B></div>
      <div id="2015Weekly" ><B>2015 - Weekly</B></div>

      <div id="2016">
        <B>HHHHHHH</B>
        <input type="radio"  checked="checked" onclick="javascript:changeDiv('2016Monthly');" />Monthly
        <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:changeDiv('2016Weekly');" />Weekly
        <div id="2016Monthly" ><B>2016 - Monthly</B></div>
        <div id="2016Weekly" ><B>2016 - Weekly</B></div>
        <script>
          function changeDiv(divId)
          {
            if(divId=='2015Monthly')
            {
              document.getElementById(divId).style.display="block";
              document.getElementById('2015Weekly').style.display="none";
            }else if(divId=='2015Weekly')
            {
              document.getElementById(divId).style.display="block";
              document.getElementById('2015Monthly').style.display="none";
            }else if(divId=='2016Monthly')
            {
              document.getElementById(divId).style.display="block";
              document.getElementById('2016Weekly').style.display="none";
            }else if(divId=='2016Weekly')
            {
              document.getElementById(divId).style.display="block";
              document.getElementById('2016Monthly').style.display="none";

            }else if(divId=='2016')
            {
              document.getElementById(divId).style.visibility="visible";
              document.getElementById('2015').style.visibility="hidden";
            }else if(divId=='2015')
            {
              document.getElementById(divId).style.visibility="visible";
              document.getElementById('2016').style.visibility="hidden";
            }
          }

        </script>
        </body>
      </html>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: the function changeDiv will be called only when the dropdown value is changed.. First time when it loads it will show all the divs,ryt?

Comment: Actually it shouldn't. I need to view only 2015 div as default ( along with monthly div enabled inside 2015). I am not able to achieve it. Appreciate ur help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (main) problem is that instead of passing the `id` your pass the string `year`.

So you need to change the `onchange` value to `this.value` so it will take the **value** of the selection (2015/2015).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <select class="dropdown" id="year" name="year" size="1" onchange="changeDiv(this.value);">
      <option value="2015" selected="selected">2015</option>
      <option value="2016">2016</option> 
    </select>

    <div id="2015">
      <B>AAAAAAA</B>
      <input type="radio" checked="checked" onclick="javascript:changeDiv('2015Monthly');" name="2015_type" />Monthly
      <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:changeDiv('2015Weekly');" align="left" name="2015_type" />Weekly

      <div id="2015Monthly" ><B>2015 - Monthly</B></div>
      <div id="2015Weekly" ><B>2015 - Weekly</B></div>
    </div>
    <div id="2016">
      <B>HHHHHHH</B>
      <input type="radio" checked="checked" onclick="javascript:changeDiv('2016Monthly');" name="2016_type" />Monthly
      <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:changeDiv('2016Weekly');" name="2016_type" />Weekly
      <div id="2016Monthly" ><B>2016 - Monthly</B></div>
      <div id="2016Weekly" ><B>2016 - Weekly</B></div>
    </div>
    <script>
      function changeDiv(divId)
      {
        if(divId=='2015Monthly')
        {
          document.getElementById(divId).style.display="block";
          document.getElementById('2015Weekly').style.display="none";
        }else if(divId=='2015Weekly')
        {
          document.getElementById(divId).style.display="block";
          document.getElementById('2015Monthly').style.display="none";
        }else if(divId=='2016Monthly')
        {
          document.getElementById(divId).style.display="block";
          document.getElementById('2016Weekly').style.display="none";
        }else if(divId=='2016Weekly')
        {
          document.getElementById(divId).style.display="block";
          document.getElementById('2016Monthly').style.display="none";

        }else if(divId=='2016')
        {
          document.getElementById(divId).style.display="block";
          document.getElementById('2015').style.display="none";
        }else if(divId=='2015')
        {
          document.getElementById(divId).style.display="block";
          document.getElementById('2016').style.display="none";
        }
      }
      $('#year').change();
      $(':checked').trigger('click');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

http://output.jsbin.com/lileze

Comment: Thank you Mosh Feu!! But, By Default, i need to have Only 2015 div enabled (also Monthly div enabled inside 2015). Here when page loads both 2015 & 2016 div are viewed. Please suggest an idea.

Comment: I made some changes like change the `visibility` to `display`. Also, I trigger the `select` and the `radio buttons` so the `change` and `click` event will fire and show/hide the right elements. If something is not clear, let me know.

Comment: I don't get where to use the trigger event and also whats the reason to name the radio buttons in both divs (2015/2016).

Comment: 1. The script in the snippet is added to the bottom of the `body`. I was updated the answer so now the `trigger` are at the bottom of the script. 2. The reason I was added the `name` attribute is becuase if you don't do this, you can check multiple radio buttons at the same time (like in your example). [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419459/how-to-set-that-only-one-radio-button-can-be-checked)

Answer (score 0):

There are some thimgs that you are missing. For example how call the function on change. The parameter of function is not the correct one.
This solution should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>



 <select  id="mySelect" name="year" size="1" onchange="myFunction()">
      <option value="2015" selected="selected">2015</option>
      <option value="2016">2016</option> 
    </select>

 <div id="2015" style="display:block">
      <B>AAAAAAA</B>

 <input type="radio"   checked="checked" onclick="javascript:changeDiv('2015Monthly');" />Monthly
      <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:changeDiv('2015Weekly');" align="left" />Weekly

      <div id="2015Monthly" ><B>2015 - Monthly</B></div>
      <div id="2015Weekly" ><B>2015 - Weekly</B></div>
      </div>

 <div id="2016" style="display:none">
        <B>HHHHHHH</B>
        <input type="radio"  checked="checked" onclick="javascript:changeDiv('2016Monthly');" />Monthly
        <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:changeDiv('2016Weekly');" />Weekly
        <div id="2016Monthly" ><B>2016 - Monthly</B></div>
        <div id="2016Weekly" ><B>2016 - Weekly</B></div>
        </div>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;

 if(x=='2016')
            {

              document.getElementById(x).style.display="block";
              document.getElementById('2015').style.display="none";
            }else if(x=='2015')
            {
              document.getElementById(x).style.display="block";
              document.getElementById('2016').style.display="none";
            }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```