# How to find out which radio button the user selected in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, haml

I have a form that looks like this 
[image]

Right now, the problem I am having is that the user can select more than 1 radio button. They should only be able to select 1.
I  have a Javascript function that will go through all the rows and disable the button that was not selected as seen here.

```
function disableNonSelectedRadioButtons(selectedRadioButton) {
    $('#payer-contract-global-table .clone-target').each(function (i)  {
        var radioName = 'radio' + '-c' + i;
        if (selectedRadioButton != radioName)
            $('#' + radioName).prop("checked", false);
    });
}
```

This works. But I need to send the correct `selectedRadioButton` to this function. How can I correctly do that in Javascript?

Currently the HAML looks like this:

```
   %input.radio-button{:name => "radio-c#{index}", :type => "radio", :id => "radio-c#{index}", :checked => "true"}
```

Is there some type of code in Javascript that I can do that says that
if I click button for `radio-c2` it will send that to my function?

Comment: Why can't you use regular HTML and [give your radio buttons the same name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419459/how-to-set-that-only-one-radio-button-can-be-checked)?

Comment: @Mdjon26 It's not clear what you asking for, clarify your issue more precisely.

Comment: Because from your Post it seems you just want is functionality that helps only one radio can be selected at a time, than you don't need javascript for that. Just do @SébastienVercammen mentioned. And if that is not what you want, elaborate more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you encounter that the event is not being triggered, It happens because the DOM element are being generated dynamically (I think...) I solve it like this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'input[type="radio"]', function(e){
   var selectedRadioName = $(this).attr('name');
   disableNonSelectedRadioButtons(selectedRadioName);
});
```

just in case.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use jQuery:

```
  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(e){
       var selectedRadioName = $(this).attr('name');
       disableNonSelectedRadioButtons(selectedRadioName);
  });
```

If you're creating elements dynamically, use event delegation: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

```
 $(document).on('click', 'input[type="radio"]', function(e){
       var selectedRadioName = $(this).attr('name');
       disableNonSelectedRadioButtons(selectedRadioName);
 });
```

That said, you can just use HTML for this:

```
<input type="radio" name="giveThemAllTheSameName" />
```

By giving the radio buttons the same name you will only be able to select one.

Comment: The JQuery works in console, but doesn't work in my application. Why is that? Do I somehow need to activate it?

Comment: Make sure you have the jQuery source (Or CDN: "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js") script tags before the above code.

You'll also want to delay the execution until the DOM loads. ie: $(document).ready(function(){
  //above code
});

Answer (score 0):

You can use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(disableNonSelectedRadioButtons($(this).prop('name')));
```

Comment: Don't use Javascript for something that is HTML's job.

Comment: The question asked specifically for Javascript though.