# how to disable one checkboxout of two check box at a time using javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-6">Gold Foil Stamping : </label>
      <div class="col-sm-6"><input type="checkbox" name="gold_foil_option" value="Gold_Silver_Printing"> Gold / Silver Printing<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="gold_foil_option1" value="Gold_Foil_Stamping"> Gold Foil Stamping</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to select one check box out of two check box using javascript? What is the possible way to select one checkbox using javascript? Can i name both the name as same so as to select one checkbox at a time? I want to use only javascript only at a time?

Comment: You should use `radio` element for it

Comment: There's something [familiar here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42152281/only-one-radio-button-must-be-selected-at-a-time#42152281), but a different user?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Only one radio button must be selected at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42152281/only-one-radio-button-must-be-selected-at-a-time)